# How is PI used to predict weather patterns?

Tags: probability, pi, pattern-recognition, constants

I've heard that using PI to predict weather patterns is possible. I would like verification on this, and how this is possible. I can't seem to find any other sources explaining this concept.

My reference to where I heard this is this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c5jep7S8yxA 
Skip to 0:14 of the video to hear where this is mentioned.

Comment: This sounds really strange to me, so strange that I'm a little curious as to why you gave no reference to where you heard/saw this.

Comment: @Dave L. Renfro Well, I didn't give any reference, because it is ridiculously brief. I will edit this now.

Comment: I asked because it sounded so strange to me that I figured you'd want to back it up, but then you didn't . . . (The only thing I can think of is maybe using the digits as a random number generator, but I have not yet listened to the youtube cite you gave.)

Comment: I don't think the video is very good from a mathematical perspective.

Comment: @Brad It's the only reference I had.

Comment: I just listened to about half of it and I agree with Brad. It occurs to me now that he might have heard somewhere computers being tested for speed (very important in weather calculations) by computing the digits of $\pi.$ But the fact that he just tosses this out in a willy-nilly way without further comment is very telling, as well as his mispronunciation of Euler's name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It comes up in weather dynamics models where volume or surface area of spheres are relevant. It's not really anything special, it's not like you can read off weather patterns from its digits.